# Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x107ca3278) to 'UITableView' (0x107c9c518)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have register cell as well but it did not perform segue in that way
here is where I get error :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.


    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        let sender = sender as! UITableView . //error
        let destController = segue.destination as! HekDetailTableViewController
        let indexPath = sender.indexPathForSelectedRow!



            destController.iD = idArray[indexPath.row]

        }

}
```

Comment: Typo: The sender is `UITableViewCell`. The error message means literally: *I'm expecting the type 'UITableViewCell' but you're giving me 'UITableView'.*

Comment: when I change it it gives me : Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'indexPathForSelectedRow'   in the next line

Comment: Use the tableView property `let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!`, the sender is then not needed

Comment: it gives me : Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController' (0x10b1c35d8) to 'ETKA.HekDetailTableViewController' (0x10825f480).

Comment: That's a different question. Is the class of the destination controller set to `HekDetailTableViewController` in Interface Builder?

Comment: ow that slved the problem thanks a lot @vadian